# How to get a smooth page transition with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router, vuetify.js

I´m new to Vue/Vuetify and have a question about the page transition/rendering on cache-refresh (in Chrome):

1. For example, I integrated a small snipped in my project: codepen.io/vreaxe/pen/oeWwOJ.
2. When I now cache-refresh (Ctrl+f5) the page (tested in Chrome) I see the content for a short time like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcrRT.png). After that, I see the rendered page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR48J.png).
3. Now I´m wondering how to fix that, so I don´t see the content before the page is fully rendered or isn´t the rendering the problem for that?
4. [Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/googleYoutube) is an example of how it should look like. On any refresh, the page renders perfectly and has a short transition in it, but I couldn't find out how to reach that.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a global loading parameter and have it false by default and then set to true in beforeMount and false in mounted.

```
//store/index.js
...
state: {
  loading: false,
},


//yourComponent.vue
<template>
  <div v-if="this.$store.state.loading">
   //a spinner or progress bar
  </div>
  <div v-else>
  //your component code
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
    beforeMount() {
      this.$store.state.loading = true
    }
    mounted() {
      this.$store.state.loading = false
    }
  }
</script>
```

These aren't called if you're using server side rendering so you have to make your loading call in a method that is called on initialisation.